# connecting bigquery to an unintended project

Tags: python, google-bigquery, gcloud

I'm following [this instruction](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/bigquery-sparkml) to write a python code and connect it to bigquery

by using

```
gcloud init
```

I choose a particular account and project

and then I run this code:

```
from gcloud import bigquery
from gcloud.bigquery import job
from gcloud.bigquery.table import *

# Create a new Google BigQuery client using Google Cloud Platform project
# defaults.
bq = bigquery.Client()
```

But it seems it connects to a wrong project. How it is possible? Does any one have any experience? this is the error.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File
>   "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\gcloud\bigquery\dataset.py", line
>   423, in create
>       method='POST', path=path, data=self._build_resource())   File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\gcloud\connection.py", line 347, in
>   api_request
>       error_info=method + ' ' + url) gcloud.exceptions.Forbidden: 403 Billing has not been enabled for this project. Enable billing at
>   https://console.cloud.google.com/billing. (POST
>   https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/**decisive-octane-142800**/datasets)

The project that I bolded belongs to my another account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Project selected in `gcloud init` is for gcloud cli tool only, and not for the python gcloud library. In fact the two are kind of unrelated (they sort of share same name).

The instructions you provided link for do not ask you to use `gcloud init`.

You can use gcloud to manage you credentials as described [here](http://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/google-cloud-auth.html).

So, instead of

```
bq = bigquery.Client()
```

you should specify project explicitly

```
bq = bigquery.Client(project=YOUR_PROJECT_ID)
```

It is also possible to specify it via other means as this is deduced by this [code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-auth-library-python/blob/master/google/auth/_default.py#L192) but it is better to be explicit as this code makes assumptions which are not guaranteed to be always true.

Comment: thank you for your information. I tried  `bq = bigquery.Client(project=YOUR_PROJEC_NAME)`  with both my project name an also project ID. None of them worked. I got 'invalid syntax' error. Do you have any clue what I am missing?

Comment: Seems like you have python syntax issue. I assume you have something like `bq = bigquery.Client(project='my-project-id')` with proper quotes etc... and yes you should use project id, (not name or number).